# undefined method email for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

How i can fix this Error

NoMethodError in Channels::Profiles#show
Showing /home/action/catarse/app/views/catarse_bootstrap/shared/_header_channel.html.slim where line #16 raised:

undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #16):
13
14
15
16
17
18
19

```
           = mail_to channel.email, t('channels.header.contact'), title: t('channels.header.contact'), class: 'standard-link', target: '_blank'
         - if current_user
           li.nav-item
             = link_to '#', class: 'user-menu' do
               = image_tag(current_user.display_image, :size => "40x40", class: 'user-avatar')
             ul.dropdown.user
               li= link_to t('channels.header.profile'), current_user
```

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/catarse_bootstrap/channels/profiles/show.html.slim

Rails.root: /home/action/catarse

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/catarse_bootstrap/shared/_header_channel.html.slim:16:in `_app_views_catarse_bootstrap_shared__header_channel_html_slim__4148437850825180179_67490200'
app/views/catarse_bootstrap/channels/profiles/show.html.slim:1:in`_app_views_catarse_bootstrap_channels_profiles_show_html_slim__2611454716947747879_66362380'
Request

Parameters:

None
Toggle session dump
Toggle env dump
Response

Headers:

None

Comment: It's clear your `channel` variable holds `nil` value. How do you set it?

Comment: Hi i'm new in ruby so i not understand what you ask? can you Explain more thanks for help

Comment: Error you have means that `channel` is nil. Can you show a line where you set it's value?

Comment: - if current_user
            li.nav-item
              = link_to '#', class: 'user-menu' do
                = image_tag(current_user.display_image, :size => "40x40", class: 'user-avatar')

Comment: Where i find this line ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer from github :

> there is something wrong with your routes. You should be in ProjectsController#index as in local server, not in ChannelsController. Take a look at config/routes.rb:31 You probably are using a subdomain that is not listed in the regex (www, secure, test and local)

https://github.com/catarse/catarse/issues/451

If you are using a sub domain you must add it in config/routes.rb 
  constraints subdomain: /^(?!www|secure|test|local|*SUBDOMAIN*)(\w+)/ do